# Prove two groups are isomorphic when one group is a set of functions

Tags: group-theory, number-theory

Consider the abelian groups $\mathrm{Map}^1(\mathbb{Z}^+, \mathbb{Z})$ and $\mathrm{Map}^1(\mathbb{Z}^+, \mathbb{Z}_2)$ (Definitions below). Show that

(a) $\mathbb{Q}^* \cong$ $\mathrm{Map}^1(\mathbb{Z}^+, \mathbb{Z})$

(b) $\mathbb{Q}^* / (\mathbb{Q}^*)^2 \cong \mathrm{Map}^1(\mathbb{Z}^+, \mathbb{Z}_2)$

Definition of $\mathrm{Map}$ and $\mathrm{Map}^1$:

$\mathrm{Map}(I, G)$:

Let $I$ be a set and $G$ an abelian group, then let $\mathrm{Map}(I, G)$ be the group of functions $f: I \rightarrow G$.

$\mathrm{Map}^1(I,G)$:

Let $\mathrm{Map}^1(I, G)$ be the set of functions $f \in \mathrm{Map}(I, G)$ such that $f(i) \neq 0_G$ for at most finitely many $i \in I$.

I don't know where to start at all, and I can't think of a map that would even relate these two groups. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

(a) Let $p_i$ denote the $i$th prime number. Then for $f\in\mathrm{Map}^1(\mathbb Z^+,\mathbb Z)$ let $\phi(f)=\prod_{i=1}^\infty p_i^{f(i)}$.

Then you modify $\phi$ in a natural way for (b).

I'll leave it to you to prove that $\phi$ and its modification for $(b)$ are isomorphisms.

Edit: Actually my answer is wrong, but only because the question is. I've given an isomorphism between $\mathrm{Map}^1(\mathbb Z^+,\mathbb Z)$ and $\mathbb Q^+$, but your question wanted an isomorphism for $\mathbb Q^*$. However $\mathbb Q^+$ and $\mathbb Q^*$ are not isomorphic (think about $-1$), so the original question was impossible, and was probably meant to ask for an isomorphism between $\mathbb Q^+$ and $\mathrm{Map}^1(\mathbb Z^+,\mathbb Z)$, in which case my answer is correct.